# Register Raspberry pi to DNS server

Tags: networking, dns

In the enterprise network, As a client how can i connect my pi to the (Windows)DNS server ? 
so that i can ssh/ping the pi by hostname without the ip address.

Eg:

```
myraspberrypi.domain.org
```

Instead of avahi-daemon and samba. Anyone have any idea to solve the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: would that not be something you would need to configure on the (Windows)DNS server perhaps? (i.e. not relevant to this forum at all)

Comment: only configure at (Windows)DNS server ? got any configuration required in raspberry pi?

Comment: does the Pi get IP address using DHCP?

Comment: Yes the pi gotten the IP address

Comment: This appears to be a question about configuring DNS in Windows. In the enterprise network, the usual way is to tell the IT personnel to set it up for you.

Comment: nsupdate is your friend. https://serverfault.com/questions/783864/windows-dns-server-register-a-non-dhcp-client-server-into-2008r2 Your question was quite high in the search results, so therefore this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Name resolution is made by asking DNS server. The RasPi has set default DNS server to ask but of course not your (Windows)DNS server. You do it by editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and insert an option

```
static domain_name_servers=
```

with the ip address of your (Windows)DNS server. There are examples in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Your DNS server should support dynDNS so it bind the host name to the ip address the host has gotten from the DHCP server. I don't know your environment if this works or if you can make it working. But you have always the option to define a static mapping in the DNS server.